# How to establish a ssh connection through python or jython and run a script remotly?

Tags: python, scripting, jython

Hi I want to know how i can establish a ssh connection through python or jython and run a script file remotly on another machine. I am not sure about the platform of the machine where i want to run the script? Please provide some sample code as well. I wont mind going for some other scripting language as well.

Comment: @chown i dont know phython i just know what i want. I did googling not convinced by my answer hence i am here to ask. Please dont be that rude.

Comment: @downvoter... its better if u explain me why did u downvoted.

Comment: @ chown http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest/quickest way would be to use Python's os.system() to call the ssh command of the system:
http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=system#os.system

E.g. this works on Ubuntu

```
import os
os.system('/usr/bin/ssh localhost ls -la /')
```

runs 'ls -la /' through ssh on localhost.

You will need to provide the proper command-line options to ssh, and you can set up the ssh keys to connect securely but without a password to a remote host for executing command(s):
check this out: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/ssh-with-keys/ or google for more info on ssh keys.

Comment: Yeah it works - but it's not a good solution, first, don't use `os.system`, look at `subprocess`. Even better, use a direct library, such as paramirko.

Comment: Depends on what you need. For a quick hack this works. Also using the system's ssh is _usually_ more secure than a separate library, unless you're using openssh lib directly.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/0.9.7/index.html):

> Fabric is a Python library and command-line tool for streamlining the
>   use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.
>
> It provides a basic suite of operations for executing local or remote
>   shell commands (normally or via `sudo`) and uploading/downloading files,
>   as well as auxiliary functionality such as prompting the running user
>   for input, or aborting execution.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/), it provide API to execute arbitrary Python code on remote machine. I use it on Linux machines but it work both in Windows and Linux.